# Using Multi-table Insert for Parent and Child Table

Tags: oracle, foreign-key

Is it safe to use Oracle's multi-table insert statement to insert into a (foreign key constrained) parent and child table?

With minimal examples, I've found that it works as long as the parent table comes before the child table in the `into` list. Can I rely on this or should I make the constraint deferrable?

Comment: Are you talking about `INSERT ALL`?

Comment: @Phil: Yes I am.

Comment: What about two inserts? Why go the roundabout way with deferrable constraints when the simple method of multiple inserts has always worked?

Comment: @Vincent sometimes it takes a fraction of the time to `insert all` - that may be Isaac's reason?

Comment: @JackDouglas Performance is a good reason, but `INSERT ALL` has lots of limitations: no parallel execution, no insert in a view. This leads me to think that this statement is less optimized that standard `INSERT` statements, especially when inserting in multiple tables.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: I'm inserting rows returned by a subquery. It is this subquery that determines the parent-child relationship; two insert statements wouldn't work.

Comment: @Vincent I didn't know those limitations, so thanks for that. May I ask if you have anything in particular against deferrable constraints?

Comment: @JackDouglas I don't have anything against deferrable referential constraints :) (although some IDE may not work nicely with them since they can make a commit fail which is something some IDE don't handle well). Some other constraints though can make the optimizer [less effective when deferrable](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/14/constraints-dont-make-them-deferrable-or-novalidate-unless-you-need-to/).

Answer (score 8):

**No**, you can't depend on this.  SQL is declarative, not procedural, so within a statement you can't guarantee the order of execution.  Since the entire `INSERT ALL` statement is considered a single statement ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50946)), you can't guarantee that one `INSERT` will be before another.

By definition an `INSERT FIRST` must execute the first `INTO` passing the evaluated conditions.  We might expect `INSERT ALL` to behave similarly.  This *appears* to be the case:

```
DROP TABLE T1;
CREATE TABLE T1 AS (SELECT 'a' c1, 0 c2, 0 c3 FROM dual WHERE 1=2);
INSERT ALL 
   WHEN mod(x,2)<>0 THEN INTO T1 VALUES ('a', x, mod(x,2)) 
   WHEN mod(x,2)=0 THEN INTO T1 VALUES ('b', x, mod(x,2)) 
   SELECT Level x FROM dual CONNECT BY Level <=20;
COMMIT;   
SELECT rowid, c1, c2, c3 FROM t1;
```

However, even though we can demonstrate a particular behavior on a particular platform/version/patchset still doesn't make this a guarantee.

[Oracle-developer.net](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=209) says it explicitly:

> the conditions in an INSERT FIRST statement will be evaluated in order
>   from top to bottom. Oracle makes no such guarantees with an INSERT ALL
>   statement.

Comment: Oracle do actually consider this non-deterministic behaviour a bug (see My Oracle Support article 265826.1 for bug 2891576). However, given this was raised back in 2003 for version 9.2.0.3, I doubt there's much chance of this being fixed anytime soon.

Comment: @Chris Saxon Excellent find.  The report demonstrates a case in which modifying the size of an unrelated column affects which into is done first.  As expected the workaround is to use `DEFERRED CONSTRAINTS`.

Answer (score 2):

Isaac,

You can not rely on this as oracle does not guarantee the order of INSERT. The correct way to do this is, as you mentioned, with the deferred foreign key constraint.

Comment: The order does not matter, as the constraints are checked _after_ the SQL command is executed. Well theoretically as due to the bug [mentioned above](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23384/using-multi-table-insert-for-parent-and-child-table/23447#comment38788_23447) it does not work correctly. See an example using an `INSERT ... SELECT` here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7de0f (note it works with PostreSQL and Oracle, but not with MySQL or MS SQL)